# Formalizing variable length recurrences of random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, graphical-model

I'm not a statistician (just a barely proficient user of rudimentary bayesian stuff in the context of ML), so the questions I have below may be very dumb and easily answered by pointing me to lecture notes about some concept I am evidently missing. If that's the case, great! I look forward to learning something new. If not, then I hope people can point me in the direction of where I should look to learn more when providing answers.

## Basic Setting

Say I have a problem whereby $T$ latent variables $Z_1, ..., Z_T$ are distributed conditioned on the previous LV in the sequence (i.e. order-1 Markov assumption), and on $X$. A graphical model for this is shown below, on the left, and made more compact on the right using [a variant of plate notation described by David Rushing Dewhurst](https://davidrushingdewhurst.com/blog/2020-07-28keep-using-plate-notation.html) (but possibly introduced by someone else).

[image: Graphical Model]

A factorization of the joint probability of $Z_{1:T}$ given $X$, as expressed by this graphical model, would be written
$$
p(Z_{1:T} = z_{1:T} | X=x) = P(Z_1 = z_1 | X=x)\prod_{i=2}^T P(Z_i = z_i | X=x, Z_{i-1} = z_{i-1})
$$

## Treating $T$ as a Random Variable

What I want to do is express the fact that *the number*, $T$, of latent variables is itself a random variable. If it helps simplify things, $P(Z_i | Z_{i-1}, X)$ is assumed to be the same for all $i$ (because we will be approximating this conditional with a parametric function, and share parameters across different $Z_i$s), i.e. the following is true
$$\forall ijabx . P(Z_i = a | Z_{i-1} = b, X = x) = P(Z_j = a | Z_{j-1} = b, X = x)$$

I would awkwardly attempt to formalise this notion of $T$ as an RV as follows:
$
p(Z_{1:T} = z_{1:\tau} | X=x, T=\tau) \\
= P(Z_1 = z_1 | X=x) \prod_{i=2}^\infty \mathbf{max}(P(Z_i = z_i | X=x, Z_{i-1} = z_{i-1}), \mathbb{I}_{\leq \tau}(i))\\
= P(Z_1 = z_1 | X=x) \prod_{i=2}^\tau P(Z_i = z_i | X=x, Z_{i-1} = z_{i-1})\\
$

where $\mathbb{I}_{\leq \tau}(i) = 1$ if $i \leq \tau$ and $0$ otherwise (so the $\mathbf{max}$ ignores $P(Z_i | \ldots)$ when $i > \tau$).

Something about this feels a bit awkward, so the first two questions are:

1. Is this a correct way to express/factorize this dependence on $T$? If not, how would I do it?
2. How would you write, in plate notation, this sort of graphical model?

## Deciding when to stop

More loosely, I want to consider the case where every time I sample a value of some $Z_i$ in the series, I also decide (conditional on the values of $Z_i$ and $X$) whether I want to sample a value for $Z_{i+1}$, or whether I'm done (as you would in a recurrence). In other words, I have a Bernoulli $P(\textit{Continue?}_i | Z_i, X)$ (I'll write $C_i$ with support 1 for "yes" and 0 for "no" as shorthand for $\textit{Continue?}_i$) which determines whether to sample a value for $Z_{i+1}$ (if $\textit{Continue?}_i = \text{yes}$) or stop at $Z_i$ (if $\textit{Continue?}_i = \text{no}$).

This yields the following three questions:

3. What is the proper way to formalise this? Is it something like $P(Z_{1:\infty},C_{1:\infty}|X)$? How does it factorize into components $P(C_i | Z_i, X)$, $P(Z_i | X_i, C_{i-1}, Z_{i-1})$? How do I express the termination condition in this formalization?
4. What is the formal relationship between $C_1, \ldots$ and $T$?
5. Is there a graphical/plate notation way to represent sort of variable length recurrence?

## A general question

This all reminds me of things like Dirichlet processes from topic modelling. Is there a name for this kind of variable-number-of-random-variables model? Are they generically stochastic processes, or a specific category of processes?

Answer (score 0):

A possible way forward would be to "pretend" you have an infinite number of $Z$ variables, then compute the distribution of $T$ conditioned on all of them, i.e.,
$$
p(T, Z_1,\ldots, Z_\infty, X)
=p(X)p(Z_1,\ldots,Z_\infty|X)p(T|Z_1,\ldots,Z_\infty)
%p(Z_1|X)\prod_{t=2}^T p(Z_t|Z_{t-1},X)
$$
without involving any "coint$C_t$ variable.

For example, imagine that you want to sample a new $Z_t$ as long as you find a value lower than any before. In this case, $T$ is defined as as the "number of observations in decreasing order", e.g., if $T=3$ then $z_3<z_2<z_1$.
You could express the distribution of $T$ starting from:
$$
p(T>t|Z_1,\ldots,Z_\infty)=p(T>t-1|Z_1,\ldots,Z_t,X)\cdot p(Z_t<Z_{t-1}|X)=\prod_{\tau=2}^T p(Z_\tau<Z_{\tau-1}|X)
$$
From here on, use the distribution of $Z_t$ to expand, simplify, etc.
For the sake of the example, if there is no $X$, and each $Z_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and independent of the others, then $p(Z_t<Z_{t-1})=p(Z_t-Z_{t-1}<0)=1/2$, since the difference is also Gaussian with zero mean. Then,
$$
p(T>t|Z_1,\ldots,Z_\infty)=\prod_{\tau=2}^t\frac{1}{2}=2^{1-t}
$$

I am also not an expert in stochastic processes, but you may want to start reading from [stopping times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time).